# what about bind and reference in c++11

Tags: c++11, compiler-errors, bind

why this code compiled in c++11 the it2 and it4 is correct.
but it1 and it3 is compiled error with non-static function?
is it bug with std compiler? or i understand the wrong about these?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
namespace test {
    class a {
        public:
            void funa() {}
    };

    class b : public a {
        public:
            void funb() { }
    };
    struct c {
        void func() {}
    };
}
int main()
{
    test::b b1;
    test::c c1;
    auto it1 = std::bind(&(test::c::func),&c1);
    auto it2 = std::bind(&test::c::func,&c1);
    auto it3 = std::bind(&test::a::funa, &b1);
    auto it4 = std::bind(&(test::a::funa),&b1);
}
```

Comment: You cannot write `&(class::memfun)`, this has nothing to do with bind or c++11 or references or much anything else really, it is just not allowed. Write `&class::memfun` with no parentheses.

Comment: but if i just changed the function to static function it is all allowed with &(class::memfun) is it any bug with compiler?  i checked the bind function, it bind the function to a left value, is it any connection with this?

Comment: Yes for static function it is allowed. Static member functions are like non-member functions. Non-static member functions are different. This is not a bug in a compiler. You can delete bind from your examles, it is irrelevant. Just `&(class::memfun);` on a line by itself is enough.

Comment: Thanks for your help very much!!